# How to remove only a part of parent category form url - Magento

Tags: php, magento

I don't know if its very simple to do or if it can be done from back-end or by modifying core files.

If I have a product in sub-category and if the url looks like this for my test-product

`http://www.domain.com/pc/subc1/subc2/test-product`

I would like to cut down just one level from there,

`http://www.domain.com/subc1/subc2/test-product3`

So always just cut down the first bit of my parent category n keep the rest intact.

How can this be done? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to change the product url.

```
Admin-panel > system > configuration > catalog > catalog > Search Engine Optimizations > Use Categories Path for Product URLs > Change to "NO".
```

Comment: I found this link `http://anuran.in/node/1833` and I tried it as well but it cuts more than 1 bit of my url. So it should ideally be `http://www.domain.com/subc1/subc2/test-product3` but it becomes `http://www.domain.com/subc2/test-product3` or If I just want this `http://www.domain.com/subc1/subc2/` it becomes `http://www.domain.com/subc2/`. How can i stop it from cutting that one extra bit

Comment: Any ideas anyone ? Even if there is a hacky solution to it, might do for now. I just need to get this working so that it only ever strips out my main parent category and keeps the rest of the sub categories intact. Please, some one suggest a working solution